# Spring method present in code, but not present in JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to invoke that method:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.0.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorProperties.java#L73

But it's not available. It's not even present in decompiled code. But it should be, since JavaDoc says it's available from 1.3.0 version and it's public. My version is 2.0.0, I also checked 1.5.4. The link I gave is for 2.0.x and in GitHub it's still there. But in code it's not available, why?

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorProperties;

public class Test {

    ErrorProperties errorProperties = new ErrorProperties();

    public Test() {
        //Cannot resolve method getWhitelabel()
        errorProperties.getWhitelabel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `mvn dependency:tree` to check your libs and versions? 
Did you compile the code via mvn or your ide?

Comment: @Peter [INFO] test:test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile I compiled via IDE.

Comment: @DOWNVOTER Care to explain? Totally valid question.

Comment: As you can see here the methods are introduced in newer 2.0.x Releases https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/161ecc05752bb557634bcede418e6f2dc8fb44e6#diff-c569e2cd72e98a6c1fd1002b89751e0b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is not in 2.0.0, nor in 2.0.3, but it is in 2.0.4 (the current latest version).

Change your `pom.xml` to:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And it will compile.

Comment: Right, `@since` applies to existence of a class, not necessarily to all methods. Now it makes sense.

Comment: @ctomek They could have also put javadoc on that method and documented it as being `@since 2.0.4`, and that would have been good of them, but, yes, the `@since` is just on the javadoc for the class.